# PHP MySQL hide rows more than 1 minute old

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a PHP chat script and **I want to make sure it doesn't display any entries older than 1 minute**. The database contains a timestamp on each row called `timestamp`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### SQL

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE timestamp > TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE))
```

It's been a while since I've used that particular function, so I might be a bit off but it's close.

#### JavaScript

It sounds like you might want to actively hide old messages.  In that case you need to include the timestamp meta-data so you can filter it using JavaScript.